# How merge two tables and average it (hourly vs daily tables)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE a (DATE TEXT, PRICE INTEGER) 
INSERT INTO a VALUES 
("2019-04-27", 10), ("2019-04-29",20), ("2019-04-30",30), ("2019-05-01",40); 

CREATE TABLE b (DATE TEXT, PRICE INTEGER) 
INSERT INTO b VALUES 
("2019-04-27 01:00", 1), ("2019-04-27 02:30)",3), ("2019-04-27 18:00",2), 
("2019-04-28 17:00",2), ("2019-04-28 21:00",5), 
("2019-04-29 17:00",50), ("2019-04-29 21:00",10), 
("2019-04-30 17:00",10), ("2019-04-30 21:00",20), 
("2019-05-01 17:00",40), ("2019-05-01 21:00",10), 
("2019-05-02 17:00",10), ("2019-05-02 21:00",6);
```

I need to merge this two tables, so that Table b is averaged to daily and table has 2 columns (1 is date (all dates are necessary to be there) and 2 is Price (Null if no observations for that date). I tried several left joins , however do not know how to tackle the problem that I cannot average hourly data to the daily.
Could you help?

Comment: Show desired result. And spectfy MySQL version - it is critical for your task.

Comment: mysql or sqlite ?

Comment: `DATE TEXT` ?? Why not use a `DateTime` data type, afterall you are giving the right format date for it to be a DateTime datatype

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I think OP is using sqlite - in this database, dates are stored as `text`.

Comment: You should really be showing the result that you expect. Your question looks interesting but without expected result I don't think anyone can take a sure shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please, execute query as per below [SQL-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f98670843c94a17a8f75a239f4c1009):

```
select DATE(c.date) as date, avg(c.price) as avg_price
from
(select date, price
from a
union all
select date, price
from b
) as c
group by DATE(c.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want a result set with two columns.  I'm not a fan of having the date be in a string datatype, but you can use string functions for what you want:

```
select date, sum(price_a) as price_a, sum(price_b) as price_b
from (select a.date, a.price as price_a, null as price_b
      from a
      union all
      select substr(b.date, 1, 10), null, price
      from b
     ) ab
group by date;
```

Comment: Thank you it is working, but what does ab mean in 7th row?

Comment: @JohnMayer . . . That is a table alias, a very important part of SQL.